# What do I do if question was put on hold for reason X, and after the edit, should be closed for reason Y?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000058/visualization-tool-for-diagramming-dependency-data) was put on hold because it asked for tools.

After [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6267820#) I consider it 'too broad' (*Does anybody know a way of turning that data into a diagram in as few steps as possible?*)

What do I do?

The mentioned close reason no longer applies to the latest content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've voted to close a question for reason X and now reason X no longer applies but reason Y does, I do not think it is worth fixing my vote. So I don't retract my vote and I if the question has been closed already, I do not vote to reopen just so that people can reclose the question with a reason that applies to the current state of the question. Mods could fix the situation but I don't think it is worth involving them, except perhaps in very rare cases, like a question closed for being a duplicate but linking to the wrong question. Having these links point to the right place has lasting value.

**The one thing I've done is put in a comment saying something like "Your reason was off-topic because X. Your edit takes care of that but now it should be closed because Y."** It helps the OP understand what is going on. Also, if the question is in the process of being closed, this helps potential close-voters follow the plot. Otherwise, they might not see why the question received votes because X, think the people who voted were just careless, do no see that Y applies, and move on. And if the question has already been closed, it may prevent the question being reopened merely because reviewers do not see evidence that X applies (which is correct) but fail to see that Y applies.

Comment: I can do that ;-)